# how to manipulate string asending and descending order in javascript and store in variable

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

someone asked a question to me to manipulate a string .Given a string `str` and I have to write a function which return manipulating `str` .

steps to manipulate

1. Find the lowest character from string .example "a"
2. Then find the another greater character which is greater than first character example "b".
3. Repeat step 2 again and again till you reach greatest character in string example "z".
4. Then find immediate smaller from remaining string example "y"
5. Repeat `4` steps till goes to smallest number.
6. repeat step 2.

Example Input string : `abcabbb`
expected output : `abcbabb`

**case 2**
Input : `aaazzz`
Output : `azazaz`

I think my approach below is not correct and I am looking for better approach. Maybe better optimised solution. I am always doing sorting:

```js
function rec(s) {
  if (!s.length) return '';
  let sortedString = s.split('').sort();
  let temp = [];
  let temp2 = []
  let res = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < sortedString.length; i++) {
    if (sortedString[i] != res[res.length - 1]) {
      res += sortedString[i]
    } else {
      temp.push(sortedString[i])
    }
  }
  console.log('before', temp)
  console.log('res', res)

  for (let i = 0; i <= temp.length; i++) {
    if (temp[i] != res[res.length - 1]) {
      res += temp[i]
    } else {
      temp2.push(temp[i])
    }
  }

  res += rec(temp2.join(''))
  //console.log(temp)
  //console.log(res);
  return res
}

function changedSort(s) {
  // Write your code here

  return rec(s);
}
console.log(changedSort('abcabbb'))
console.log(changedSort('aaazzz'))
```

Comment: No actually I think my approach is not correct

Comment: looking for better approach..may be better optimise solution . I am always doing sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider that there are (only) 26 letters, then you could just collect the count of each, and then keep zigzagging over the alphabet producing characters when a counter is still positive, and then decreasing it.

This is not always the fastest, especially not for short input or input that doesn't vary much in its letters, but 26 is a constant, and at most `len(input)` sweeps over the alphabet will be needed, so it has a linear time complexity.

```js
function order(s) {
    if (s == "") return s;
    let letters = [..."abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];
    let counts = Object.fromEntries(letters.map(c => [c, 0]));
    for (let c of s) counts[c]++;
    let zigzag = letters.slice(0, -1).concat(letters.slice(1).reverse());
    let res = "";
    while (true) {
        for (let c of zigzag) {
            if (!counts[c]) continue;
            res += c; 
            if (res.length === s.length) return res;
            counts[c]--;
        }
    }
}

console.log(order("abcabbb"));
console.log(order("aaazzz"));
```

### When the character set is large

When the input string can contain any character, not only a through z, then you can go for something you already did: collect the letters from the input and sort them. But I would still only collect unique characters and maintain a count.

Only one line in the above code would need to change:

```js
function order(s) {
    if (s == "") return s;
    let letters = [...new Set(s)].sort(); // <---
    let counts = Object.fromEntries(letters.map(c => [c, 0]));
    for (let c of s) counts[c]++;
    let zigzag = letters.slice(0, -1).concat(letters.slice(1).reverse());
    let res = "";
    while (true) {
        for (let c of zigzag) {
            if (!counts[c]) continue;
            res += c; 
            if (res.length === s.length) return res;
            counts[c]--;
        }
    }
}

console.log(order("abcabbb"));
console.log(order("aaazzz"));
```

Comment: You are assuming no capitals, no punctuation, and no Unicode.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I am assuming.

Comment: But with a simple `for (let c of s) counts[c] = (counts[c] || 0) + 1;` you can find out the counts without specifying the alphabet, and then `let letters = Object.keys(counts).sort();` to get only the letters you want. 
 This will remove all such assumptions.  If the number of letters is large, you're just slightly less efficient than hoped for, that's all.

Comment: Sure, that's all.